# Send Data as props to other component using history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have my BikeCardContainer in which when I click on button it should navigate to other page and send current object data

```
handleClick() {
console.log(this.props.bikes);
this.props.propdata.history.push({
  pathname: '/Checkout',
  state: this.props.bikes
});
```

}

and I want to know how to access this data in receiving page.

```
    class Checkout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.bikes)
    this.state = {};
    this.confirmClick = this.confirmClick.bind(this);
    this.goBackClick = this.goBackClick.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass like this

```
handleClick() {
console.log(this.props.bikes);
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/Checkout',
  state: this.props.bikes
});
```

Access like this

```
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location);
```

in Class component

```
this.props.location
```

Comment: how to access data in class components, I think useLocation() is used in hooks

Comment: @Chandureddy udated for class component